# compile problems in c++ concurrency in action listing 9.9(msvc 12.0)

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread, thread-local-storage

I am trying to compile this on msvc 12.0, the code in the book uses the keyword thread_local but it seems msvc 12.0 does not support this? Instead of using thread_local I tried __declspec(thread) but I get the following compiler error:

```
Error   1   error C2483: 'this_thread_interrupt_flag' : object with constructor or destructor cannot be declared 'thread'
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <future>

class interrupt_flag
{
public:
    void set()
    {
        flag.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    bool is_set() const
    {
        return flag.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> flag;

};

__declspec(thread) interrupt_flag this_thread_interrupt_flag;

class interruptible_thread
{
public:

    template<typename FunctionType>
    interruptible_thread(FunctionType f)
    {
        std::promise<interrupt_flag*> p;
        internal_thread = std::thread([f, &p] {
                p.set_value(&this_thread_interrupt_flag);
                f();
            });
        flag = p.get_future().get();
    }

    void interrupt()
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            flag->set();
        }
    }

private:
    std::thread internal_thread;
    interrupt_flag* flag;
```

};

Is there any workarounds for this in msvc 12.0?

Comment: As you've discovered, MSVC doesn't support `thread_local` yet (nor does it support thread-safe static local variable initialization), but it will in the next version (14). You have to use mutexes or simply avoid this limitation until then, unfortunately.